# RDF: namespace to identify programming languages (JS, C#,...)

Tags: namespaces, rdf, vocabulary

I want to store serialized code and in what programming language this code is written as RDF. For example something like that:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/mynnamespace#>.
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>.

:algorithm dc:format "application/javascript";
           :code """<script>alert('test');</script>""";
           :language <URI?>.
```

What would you suggest how to identify the programming language? Do you know any existing vocabulary? If not, what URI would you use for e.g. JavaScript, C#, Python...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the URIs from [DBpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBpedia) (which uses Wikipedia as base):

```
 :language <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Python_(programming_language)>.
```

Or from [Freebase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebase).